# Asp.NET Update dropdownlist in a row [item] in listview without reloading the whole listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, asp.net-ajax

I have a listView with two dropdownlists [ddls] in each item [row], when I select an option from the first dropdown list, the second ddl reloads different content.

I currently have the whole listview wrapped in an `updatePanel`. I tried putting the updatePanel for those two `<td>` [column], but it seems not compile that way, how can I achieve this using JS and JQuery?

Comment: Do you have all the information on the client side to change the content of the second DropDownList? Or do you need to get data from the server after selecting an item in the first list?

Comment: I will need to get it from the server, but I can load it all on the client side if needed (oh, you mean just make the choices invisible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an UpdatePanel for the second DropDownList and setting the first DropDownList as a trigger seems to work and does not refresh the whole page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The event handler for the first list would look like this:

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl1 = sender as DropDownList;
    DropDownList ddl2 = ddl1.NamingContainer.FindControl("ddl2") as DropDownList;

    // Modify the second DropDownList
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you prefer using a ListView instead of a GridView, you can obtain the equivalent result with this markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: I switched to GridView and it worked, but for the accuracy of the question, is there a way to do it with ListView?

Comment: Sorry, I used a GridView in my tests and forgot that your question was about the ListView. I updated my answer to give the equivalent code for the ListView.